# PowerShell: kill/find all processes for current user except whitelist

Tags: powershell

On my CI (Jenkins) slaves, I'd like to kill all leftover processes after/before a build. (*Yes, I know that Jenkins tries to do this for me, but doesn't always succeed*).

The heuristic is :

- Current User processes only
- Except a process whitelist (any process essential for jenkins agent) eg:

  - jenkins-swarm
  - conhost type things.

I found ways to find current user's processes, and I found ways to kill processes, but not how to combine them (ideally into a one-liner)

Comment: So you just want to kill all the current user processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have Jenkins run pre/post build (Tested on Windows Server 2016):
*Remove backticks if using as a one-liner*

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process `
   | ? { ([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name) -match $_.GetOwner().User } `
   | ? {$_.CommandLine -notmatch 'conhost|swarm|jenkins-.*bat' -and $_.Name -notmatch 'System Idle|^System$' } `
).Terminate()
```

And to list them visually (I run this before I run the terminate version above), last line is different:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process `
   | ? { ([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name) -match $_.GetOwner().User } `
   | ? {$_.CommandLine -notmatch 'conhost|swarm|jenkins-.*bat' -and $_.Name -notmatch 'System Idle|^System$' } `
) | Select-Object Handle,Name,CommandLine | Format-List | Out-String -width 9999
```

Both are run via `powershell -c`